# UnsafeArrayList using sun.misc.unsafe?

Tags: java, arraylist

Have there any way or library which use to implement `UnsafeArrayList` using `sun.misc.unsafe` lib which can use as a  replacement or much faster method  than `java.util.ArrayList` ?

Comment: What would you do differently with Unsafe which would be faster?  You could use copy memory for potentially faster shifting of the values in the array but it would be better to not perform those operations in the first place.  Unsafe doesn't make everything faster as the JIT tends to optimise pure Java code more efficiently.

Comment: i need to deal with object count more than 50000. offheap is fast when allocating memory at first . but the problem is its hard when using arraylist;

Comment: You can't allocate objects off heap.  You can only allocate raw memory which is why it is fast.  Note: An ArrayList only stores references to objects, not the data itself.

Comment: BTW I have implemented very large off heap arrays for storing data, but that is different to what an ArrayList does. https://github.com/OpenHFT/Java-Lang/blob/master/lang/src/main/java/net/openhft/lang/collection/HugeArray.java

Comment: problem is how to work with dynamically allocating memory and take the advantage of using offheap !!

Comment: The best solution is to implement an off heap data structure.  This way you manage when you add and remove data.  This is what we do with Chronicle Map and Chronicle Queue.

Comment: yeah!! i agree with it.. i cant use chronicle map/queue because of some licence issues of it.

Comment: What are the licensing issues? Are you planning to redistribute a product to other companies?